# TextView: How to set image on selection

Tags: android

I am using a textview:

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView_setup_menu_msa"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_member_menu_msa"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView_event_menu_msa"
     android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
     android:text="@string/string_setup_menu_msa"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="8pt" 
     android:onClick="onCLick"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:background="@drawable/textview_selector"/>
```

i want to set selector image when click on textview like listview  and i have done like this: In res/drawable/textview_selector.xml,

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_enabled="true"
         android:state_pressed="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/selectioncell" />
      <item 
         android:state_enabled="true"
         android:state_focused="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/selectioncell" />

      <item android:state_enabled="true"
         android:state_selected="true" 
         android:drawable= "@drawable/selectioncell" /> 
   </selector>
```

Here "selectioncell" is an image. But i am not getting the proper size of the image while selecting the textview. i want full cell to be selected not only the textview. Is there any way to do like listview?

Comment: make your textview width : match_parent.

Comment: Yeah I am doing that only..Thanks.

Comment: I have solved the issue now textview selection is just look like listview selection by increasing the textview width and ht.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that if the textview_selector.xml set for TextView, not for your ImageView.
Set that selector to your ImageView and call yourimageview.performClick() in your TextView onClickListener. It might be helpfull.